# Error (1054) : Unknown column 'enable_flag' in 'field_list'

Tags: php, mysql

I was bee-bopping along writing code and testing it when I hit this error.

```
update products set enable_flag='Y' where prod_id=31745
ERROR @ 214 : (1054)
Unknown column 'enable_flag' in 'field list'
```

The "enable_flag" field is listed in the table.  I have tried several variants of the above SQL command.  I've put backticks around "products", around "enable_flag", I've tried retyping the command - all to no avail.  I even thought that maybe I'd exceeded the length limit of 65,536 characters - but no.  So I came here, read up on other's having a similar problem but those were all "You mistyped X" or "You left off the name of the table" and so forth.  This has got me a bit stumped. I'm using MySQL (latest version), PHP 5.4.12, and before yesterday I have mainly worked with the first half of the table.  So now I'm starting to work with the second half and this happens.  Also, enable_flag is column 52.  I know you can have 4096 columns.  However, anything from column 52 on can not be updated, inserted, etc....

Here is the table "products" dump:

```
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| prod_id            | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sku                | varchar(40)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| upc                | varchar(40)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title              | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| long_desc          | mediumtext    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cat_id             | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| size               | varchar(80)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| color              | varchar(80)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| model              | varchar(80)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| quantity           | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| stock_status_id    | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| image_id           | bigint(20)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mfg_id             | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| shipping           | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price              | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| points             | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tax_class_id       | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| weight             | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| width              | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| length             | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| height             | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| viewed             | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_used          | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_added         | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_modified      | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_available     | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sellor_id          | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sellor_product_id  | varchar(80)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state_codes        | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ground_ship_only   | varchar(1)    | YES  |     | n       |                |
| adult_sig_req      | varchar(1)    | YES  |     | n       |                |
| no_drop_ship       | varchar(1)    | YES  |     | n       |                |
| priority           | int(3)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| unlimited_stock    | varchar(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| reorder_level      | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| license_key        | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| store_cost         | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| msrp               | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| handling_cost      | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| min_order_quantity | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| max_order_quantity | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| weight_major       | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| weight_minor       | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| warehouse          | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| shipping_msg       | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category_special   | varchar(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| homepage_special   | varchar(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| shipping_option    | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| product_type       | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| related_products   | mediumtext    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| product_url        | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| enable_flag        | varchar(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| purchasable        | varchar(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price_msg          | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| in_stock_msg       | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| out_of_stock_msg   | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| variations         | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| attributes         | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| delete_flag        | varchar(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| short_desc         | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cross_ref          | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| model_no           | varchar(40)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pkg_qty            | int(11)       | YES  |     | 1       |                |
| military_spec      | varchar(40)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| grips              | varchar(80)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: the 4096 colums is not a fix number. The actual number depends on row size. Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html

Comment: **Every table has a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes. This maximum applies to all storage engines, but a given engine might have additional constraints that result in a lower effective maximum row size.** (Same source as @andrew but I didn't refresh to see his comment ^^)

Comment: Maybe you can squeeze out some more bytes from your columns by using better types. Your flags can be changed from `varchar(1)` to `char(1)` or even better `tinyint`. I think text and similar types arent counted as they are kept in a special store.

Comment: I just solved it.  For unknown reasons I needed to make the command "update store.products set enable_flag='Y' where prod_id=31750".  Which is really weird since there is an INSERT command to that same table not five lines of PHP code away and it works without the lower half of the table included.  Oh well - thanks everyone for looking at this.  Can this be marked solved?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the problem was the database became confused on what I actually wanted to do.  There is only one "products" table so the database should not have become confused - but it did.  The solution is to add the database's name on to the command so there isn't any confusion.  So the command should have been:

```
update store.products where enable_flag='Y' where prod_id=31750
```

By placing the "store" part on to the command, the database.table connection is then established and the field is found.

Comment: OK!  Time for "Just HOW dumb are you?" questions.  :-)  It turns out that on the Mysqli line where you open communications to the database I had database A on that line instead of the "store" database so mysql was trying to write to a non-existent field.  The problems with working with multiple databases on multiple machines.  So the real answer is - be sure you are working with the database you THINK you are working with.  Ugh.  I feel so dumb.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `enable_flag` might have other characters.  You can figure this out using `information_schema.columns`:

```
select concat('"', c.column_name, '"')
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name = 'products' and column_name like '%enable%';
```

If you find extra characters, you will probably need backticks.

Comment: `select length(c.column_name)` would work too. should come back as 11 if there aren't any invisible chars.

Comment: No - but good idea.  :-)  I'd already checked that as a possibility.  I try to catch all of the "I feel so dumb" kinds of things.  NOT that I DO always find them - but I do try to find them.  Now it has switched from enable_flag to license_option.  I probably HAVE done something dumb with that.  Mainly because I've modified the command so many times trying to find the error I've probably introduced a different error.  Ugh.